# Error Cannot convert Array to (class)[] in making a recurring calendar event with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a recurring event in a Google Calendar but I keep getting the following error: Cannot convert Array to (class)[]

The problem lies in that I am trying to grab data from a cell to fill in the class. The code is the following:

```
var recur4 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeeks([rep]);
var ne4 = c.createAllDayEventSeries(title, start, recur4, options);
```

Now, the variable rep is equal to cell H2 which has the following text in it: 31,36

When I put Logger.log(rep); it outputs 31,36 so there is no problem there either.

When I take out rep and put in 31,36 in the brackets, the script works perfectly and adds the events to the calendar, so I know that the problem is not anywhere else in the script.

I suppose that the problem has to do with the formatting in the cell, but I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

OK so based on the comment below, I changed the script to the following:

```
  var sp = rep.split(",");
  for(var i=0; i<sp.length; i++) { sp[i] = +sp[i]; } 
  var recur4 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeeks(sp);
  var ne4 = c.createAllDayEventSeries(title, start, recur4, options);
```

This got rid of the error, BUT now it is adding events every Friday. In the debugger, it now shows that the array is an integer array and comes out like this: [31,36] which should represent the two weeks I need, but something still does not work and the recur4 remains as undefined instead of an object.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments that people gave below, the final script that worked fine was the following:

```
var recur4 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().onlyOnWeeks(rep.split(",")).onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY);
var ne4 = c.createEventSeries(title, start, stop, recur4, options);
```

Comment: show the code that creates `rep`. Odds are `rep` is a `String`, not an `Array` of `Strings`. You may want `.onlyOnWeeks(rep.split(","));`

Comment: ok so that got rid of the error, and I checked the debugging, and yes, the first time around, it took 31,36 as a string, then, using your suggestion it took it as an array but now the problem is that it simply ignored the array and put an event every Friday, instead of putting it only on the 3rd of August and on the 7th of September (the two Fridays that correspond to number 31 and 36 weeks).

Comment: In the debugger, recur4 just became undefined by doing that, so it basically ignored the .onlyOnWeeks(rep.split(",")); at the end.

Comment: ok, looking at it more, it might be that in the array, the numbers are being taken as strings because the array it is giving me is ["31","36"], so the question is how to transform this string array into an integer array and that might fix it.

Comment: there are a lot of ways to coerce a number from a string in JavaScript. Consider combining one of them with `Array#map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have with your `EventRecurrence` specification is that you are specifying that this event should repeat weekly, but then use a restriction that is incompatible with a weekly restriction.

If you describe your condition with words, note that you cannot avoid saying "year". This is a strong indication that perhaps your recurrence period is incorrect.
E.g. "repeat this event every week, on weeks 31 and 36 of the year" vs. "repeat this event every year, on weeks 31 and 36"

Indeed, changing your restriction from weekly to yearly results in a valid `RecurrenceRule`:

```
var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
    .addYearlyRule()
    .onlyOnWeeks(rep.split(",").map(
      function (week) {
        return parseInt(week, 10);
      })
    );
```

References:

- [`onlyOnWeeks`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#onlyonweeksweeks)
- [`addYearlyRule`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#addyearlyrule)

PS: the `EventRecurrence` and `RecurrenceRule` classes are pretty much interchangeable.